# How to use a JSON subquery in a MySQL JSON Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, json

Following scenario: I have got a JSON data column named 'address' in my sql table. I inserted an array of objects into it. Later I will need to pick a whole object of the array by finding out which `type` in the request will be passed. 
So if I pass a `{ "type": "shipping" }` to my REST API I would like to get all the data in the object with the type "shipping" marked.

Just one of the different JSON formats I tried:

```
{
    "address": [
        {
            "type": "shipping",
            "street": "streetName",
            "streetNumber": "1"
        },
        {
            "type": "billing",
            "street": "streetName",
            "streetNumber": "2"
        },
        {
            "type": "custom",
            "street": "streetName",
            "streetNumber": "3"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is how the data gets stored in the single column:

```
[
{"type": "custom", "street": "streetName", "streetNumber": "1"}, 
{"type": "shipping", "street": "streetName", "streetNumber": "2"}, 
{"type": "billing", "street": "streetName", "streetNumber": "3"}
]
```

So I tried to do some magic with the JSON function of MySQL. Querys like

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(address, 'one', 'shipping')
FROM user_data;
```

works acutally fine but it is not the result I need. So I thought about using subquerys

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(address, (SELECT JSON_SEARCH(address, 'one', 'shipping')))
FROM user_data
WHERE user_id = 1;
```

but this just ends up with "invalid JSON path expression" (Error Code: 3143).
I already tried with different querys and JSON data formats like instead using an array I tried to insert the data like

```
"address": {
    "shipping": {
        "street": ...
        .
     },
    "billing": {
        "street": ...
        .
    }
}
```

Now I am just getting confused and it seems like there is just the mysql documentation which does not help right now...

Comment: Why are you using JSON for the addresses, instead of creating a second table `Addresses` with normal columns for `type`, `street`, `streetNumber`, etc.? Then you can store one address per row in the `Addresses` table, and find it easily.

Comment: I want to build a CRM system and the client who is storing his customer's data shall be able to add addresses for the customer as many as he wishes. So maybe he ends up with 10000 customers and each has maybe 2-5 addresses. I would like to prevent to have thounds of rows because of scaleablity and perferomance issues... but if the number of data would not effect this I would also be fine to do a seperate table. (the same will be for contact data, personal data and more... I also would like to prevent having thousands of tables)

Comment: + every client can have other requirements... maybe someone needs 10 additionally columns... to edit this tables will be more work (I guess) than using simple document objects

Comment: But as you're discovering, it's nearly impossible to _search_ the JSON data. It is at least much more complex.

Comment: Sad... this could have make my life so much easier. All right then I will stick with your proposal. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your query generate invalid JSON path expression because the result contains quotes

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(address, 'one', 'shipping')
FROM user_data;

Result: "$[0].type"
```

You can strip those quotes with REPLACE function

```
SELECT REPLACE( JSON_SEARCH(address, 'one', 'shipping'), '"', '')
FROM user_data;

Result: $[0].type
```

To get the object path, you should replace also '.type' from the end of the result

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE( JSON_SEARCH(address, 'one', 'shipping'), '"', ''), '.type', '')
FROM user_data;


Result: $[0]
```

Final query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
JSON_EXTRACT(
    address,
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            (SELECT JSON_SEARCH(address, 'one', 'billing') FROM user_data), 
            '"', 
            '' ), 
        '.type', 
        '')
) 
FROM user_data 
WHERE user_id = 1;
```

Example here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mYBXEs3M4xFDGeQvGwUgqQ/0